# Razor nested Layouts with different style in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I our project we are working with different bounded context and I am assign to one area of the domain.

We have `_MasterLayout.cshtml` that is our default layout in which doesn't implement twitter bootstrap and I have a `_SubLayout.chstml` in which I implement bootstrap.

The problem is that the style from `_MasterLayout` was override by the style from the `_SubLayout`.

Edit: Here is how I render the view.

**~/Views/_MasterLayout.cshtml** - no bootstrap implementation

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                @RenderSection("styles", false)
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class='siteMapMenuItems'></div>
                @RenderSection("SubSection")
                @RenderBody()
            </body>
        </html>
```

**~/Views/_SubLayout.cshtml**

```
    @ {
         Layout = "~/Views/_MasterLayout.cshtml";
      }


    @section styles
    {  
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Areas/xxx/css/bootstrap.css")" />
     }

    <div>
       @section SubSection {
           <h1>Title</h1>
       }
    @RenderBody()
    @section ContentSection{
        @RenderSection("ContentSection")
    }
    </div>
```

**~/Views/Content.cshtml**

```
@ {
     Layout = "~/Views/_SubLayout.cshtml";
  }

<div>
<p>Main Content</p>
@section ContentSection{
    <div>Footer<div>
}
</div>
```

Is there a way to prevent the `_MasterLayout` to adopt the bootstrap from the `_SubLayout`?

Comment: why you have sub master pages? Can you show example how you render it

Comment: Hi Teo, it was built 7 years ago I believe the developer that time is not connected with company anymore. Our PO wants to see the same layout when accessing the module and our Team Lead wants to resuse the masterlayout as much as possible.

Comment: Well, you can just delete `@section styles` from your `_SubLayout` or this is not what you want?

Comment: if it was me, i'd add bootstrap to the masterlayout, and fix whatever issues you're having when bootstrap is included.. or you need 2 different master pages

Comment: I can't remove it because my front-end framework was bootstrap and I want the `_MasterLayout` not to adopt the boostrap from the `_SubLayout` because it's components class doesn't implement bootstrap

Comment: Hi @JamieD77, yeah that's what I thought and I already suggested it to my lead but apparently he want's to reuse it as much as possible. The `_MasterLayout` contains header, profile menu, messages, navigation menu which does not implement bootstrap. From the time that I got into the project the context that I currently working on is already halfway of the development and I'm not aware that it needs to implement the `_MasterLayout` since the context has it's own menu etc.

Comment: This question makes no sense. MVC layouts utilize an inheritance hierarchy. Adding bootstrap to the sub layout doesn't add it to the master layout. If the view uses the sub layout, then it will have bootstrap via the sub layout code, but If the view uses the master layout directly, then no bootstrap. The only reason the master layout is even involved is because your sub layout builds on top of it, namely by adding things like bootstrap.